# How can I make an H4 element behave like an HR when floats are present

Tags: html, css, css-float

Here's my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/beA4a/

```
<div style="float:right; width:200px; border:solid 1px #000; height:300px;"></div>
<p>Text</p>
<hr/>
<h4 style="border-bottom:solid 1px #000;">H4 Text</h4>
```

Notice how the `hr` stops at the floated div but the h4 passes right thru it. Is there any CSS I can apply to the h4 to make it behave the same way without specifying a width on the h4?

I want it so that if the h4 was pushed below the floated div it would then take up the full page width as the hr would.

Comment: "Notice how the hr stops at the floated div but the h4 passes right thru it." That's because an `hr` is a (newly defined) paragraph-level element, and an `h4` a block-level element. But I'm not getting the question. You stated: "I want it so that if the h4 was pushed below the floated div it would then take up the full page width as the hr would." Shouldn't it be the other way around? And then still: if the `hr` is pushed down to below the floated div, it by default takes up the full width. Please explain, because these threads are Google-indexed.

Comment: @Frank Conjin My goal was to make the h4 take up all available width in its container without intersecting with floated elements. If I had set a width on the h4 to prevent it from intersecting with the floated div it would have kept that same width even if the h4 were below the floated div and didn't need to be width constrained. I didn't want that. If it were below the div, and the div no longer in its way, I wanted the h4 to take up the full width of its container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `overflow: hidden` to the `h4`

```
h4{
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/beA4a/3/)